# (DOORS/DXL) Do multiple reads from a module cause multiple operations serverside?

Tags: scripting, ibm-doors

I am trying to design my DOORS/DXL script to be efficient in terms of server usage.
I would like to know if multiple reads of certain values from a module cause multiple server actions.

Here is some pseudo code

```
for N objects in aModuleOtherThanTheCurrentlyOpenModule{
      read object N's text
}
```

Lets say N = 1million. Will this cause 1million accesses to the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the module,

```
Module m = read(aModuleOtherThanTheCurrentlyOpenModule, false)
```

Then it should be loading the entire module to the local client. That would mean that accessing any of the information in the module would be client side at that point. Until you close it via,

```
close m
```

However, future releases of DOORS (i.e. DOORS Next Generation which has not yet been released) are unlikely to function this way.